# Does VS2012/2013 auto run every test after build, or just those touching affected code?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In VS2012/2013 you can switch on the feature to execute unit tests after each build. I've used this before and  it's very nice indeed.

However, what isn't clear to me is whether this feature is clever enough to only execute unit tests for the code you have just edited (similar to what NCrunch does), rather then executing all the tests.

Could someone clarify how this works please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been a really nice if it has been supported by [Run Tests After every build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx#BKMK_Run_tests_after_every_build)
Unfortunately not, and as far as I know there is no customization on this either. It just runs all your tests after every successful build compilation.

What I do find is the "[CodeLens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx)" feature provide some assistance in identifying impacted tests for the Subject/Method has been tested. Again no real time feedback as NCrunch, but it certainly assist you in figure in out the impacted tests, for a given method.

What nice thing about this is you can just run the impacted tests within the CodeLens window popup, without even looking at the TestExplorer window.

Comment: Yeah my suspicion was that all tests are executed, which is a bit lame really, especially as we have many unit tests in the suite so a full test run can take a good few seconds. Not exactly a "continuous" experience :( Maybe CodeLens is a bit more clever? Lucky for those who can afford Ultimate edition $$$$ http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4150271-make-codelens-available-outside-of-ultimate

Comment: Could not agree more. Well said :)

Comment: @JasonEvans I forgot - here some additional note: There is a tool that similar NCrunch, less features called http://continuoustests.com/ This  also have "So, instead of running all tests, it will only run those affected by your changes."

Comment: Ahh yeah, forgot about that one :) Cheers for that, will take a look at it, since it's been a long time (about 2 years or so) since I last tried it out.

Comment: Just tried out Continous Tests, but it looks like the project is dead? Doesn't work with VS2013, plus I can't seem to find the Google Group they had for support questions. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Haven't tried with 2012/2013 though. But remember it was fine with 2010. May be it is not continuing.

Comment: Yeah, "Game over dude, game over!" :) Ah well.